# How to effectively use a VirtualBox VM on multiple computers?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

My IDE is Eclipse, running in Ubuntu 12.10 inside a VirtualBox VM. I currently work in two locations - one office has a Windows 7 PC, the other has a Mac.  It seemed most efficient to move my VM onto a high-speed USB flash drive, then carry it between offices. It hasn't worked out.

I used the PC to copy the VM to the flash drive, and tested it there. It worked. I took it to the other office, plugged it into the Mac, started VirtualBox and tried to boot the VM. It said 'can't find drive at E:...' It expected a Windows drive location. So, I tried removing the disk from the VM and re-mounting it on the Mac. That resulted in a 'UUID already in use' error.

Is this transport method possible? I don't want to have to run sethduuid every time I change offices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VirtualBox configuration files contain paths for the virtual hard disks, so copying them to another host is problematic. The simplest solution would be to create two similar configurations, one on each host and just copying the disk file to the external flash drive. Configure the paths to the disk file on each host independently so they fit your platform.

The drawback is, that you have to maintain two configurations. But they shouldn't change that often anyway.

The UUID error happens, if try to add another disk image to the virtual media manager with a UUID that match an already existing disk image. This might be because you copied a disk image in the past without replacing the UUID. Check your disk files for duplicate UUIDs.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I set up a new configuration on the Mac yesterday, linked it to the flash drive, and edited a file. This morning I built the Win7 config, attached the .vmdk and launched. It runs, and I can see the edited file as expected.